# Difference between calculating in line or two lines

Tags: c++, debugging

Here is my code in C++. I'm using g++-11 with gcc version 11.2.0.

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<vector> 
#include<algorithm>
#include<cmath>
#include<map>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    string t="90071992547409929007199254740993";
    //separateNumbers(t);
    unsigned long long stringNum=0;
    for (int j=16;j<32;j++)
    {
        stringNum += (t[j]-'0')*pow(10,32-j-1);
        
    }
    cout << stringNum;
    
    return 0;
}
```

This simple code, which I expected to get the last 16 digits as a number, gives 9929007199254740992, not 9929007199254740993.

However, the change of code

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<vector> 
#include<algorithm>
#include<cmath>
#include<map>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    string t="90071992547409929007199254740993";
    //separateNumbers(t);
    unsigned long long stringNum=0;
    for (int j=16;j<32;j++)
    {
        unsigned long long temp = (t[j]-'0')*pow(10,32-j-1);
        stringNum += temp;
        
    }
    cout << stringNum;
    
    return 0;
}
```

gives the desired result, 9007199254740993. How can we explain such a difference between two codes?

Comment: `pow` is a floating point function -- it is not an integer-based function.  Do not use floating-point functions if your program is supposed to be dealing with integers.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Aha, I see! Thank you very much! Maybe that is the problematic part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [@PaulMcKenzie's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71879337/difference-between-calculating-in-line-or-two-lines#comment127018050_71879337), the source of the difference is mixing floating-point arithmetics with integers.

Some more info for those who are interested:

The difference manifests in the last iteration of your loop.
In the **first case**, you have:

```
stringNum += (t[j]-'0')*pow(10,32-j-1);
```

which is equivalent to:

```
stringNum = stringNum + (t[j]-'0')*pow(10,32-j-1);
```

`pow` returns a `double`, and so the expresion `(t[j]-'0')*pow(10,32-j-1)` will be of type `double`, as well as: `stringNum + (t[j]-'0')*pow(10,32-j-1)`.
The value you expect (9007199254740993) cannot be represented in a `double`. The closest value is: 9007199254740992. When assigned back to integer `stringNum` it stays **9007199254740992**.
You can see more about this issue here: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

You can also see this easily if you try the following lines (your compiler will also give a **warning** about the possible loss of precision):

```
double d = 9007199254740993;
std::cout.precision(17);
std::cout << d << std::endl;
```

Which prints: `9007199254740992`.

In the **second case** you assign the value for the last digit to `temp`:

```
unsigned long long temp = (t[j]-'0')*pow(10,32-j-1);
```

`(t[j]-'0')*pow(10,32-j-1)` is a `double` with value 3, which incidently can be represented in a `double`. Then it gets assigned into an integer `temp` which is also 3.
When you execute:

```
stringNum += temp;
```

You use integer arithmetic and get the correct result: **9007199254740993**.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for the nice explanation! Now I totally get it!